# stop refreshing page on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I need to make the asp button to not refresh the whole page when I click it.

my code is just to make a picture change to another picture but the index of the picture is set in the page load method. And every time you click the button to go to the next picture index, the whole page refreshes and calls the page load method. That then sets the index back to 0.

how can I make the page stop calling the page load method when I click a button

Here's the basic code I'm using

in a table:

```
<tr>
    <td> <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Prev" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="return false"/> </td>
    <td> <img ID="pic" alt="" src="010.JPG" runat="server" width="200" height="200" /> </td>
    <td> <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Next" OnClick="Button2_Click" OnClientClick="return false"/> </td>
</tr>
```

and this is the .cs file

```
private List<String> imagePathList = new List<String> { };
private List<Boolean> isActivePath = new List<Boolean> { };

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Debug.WriteLine("GALLARY *page load*");

        pic.Width = 200;
        pic.Height = 200;

        addToList();

        getImagePath(1);
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("GALLARY *Button1_Click*");
    int index = getActive();
    getImagePath(index = index - 1); 
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("GALLARY *Button2_Click*");
    int index = getActive();
    getImagePath(index = index + 1);
}

private void getImagePath(int index)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("GALLARY *getImagePath* index = "+index);
    int length = imagePathList.Count;

    if (index < length && index >= 0)
    {
        //pic.Src = imagePathList[index];
        //pic.Alt = imagePathList[index];
        pic.Src = imagePathList[index];
        pic.Alt = imagePathList[index];
        setActive(index);
    }
    else
    {
        pic.Src = "DOES NOT EXIST";
        pic.Alt = "DOES NOT EXIST";
    }
}

private void addToList()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("GALLARY *addToList*");
    imagePathList.Clear();
    isActivePath.Clear();

    addImage("08.JPG");
    addImage("09.JPG");
    addImage("010.JPG");
    addImage("011.JPG");
    addImage("012.JPG");
}

private void addImage(String filename)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("GALLARY *addImage* filename = "+filename);
    imagePathList.Add(filename);
    isActivePath.Add(false);
}
private void setActive(int index)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("GALLARY *setActive* index = " + index);
    for (int i = 0; i > isActivePath.Count; i++)
    {
        isActivePath[i] = false;
    }

    isActivePath[index] = true;
}
private int getActive()
{
    Debug.Write("GALLARY *getActive*");
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i > isActivePath.Count; i++)
    {
        if (isActivePath[i] == true)
        {
            temp = i;
        }
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("index = " + temp);
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: set `postback` property on `Button` to false

Comment: I think u want updatepannel

Comment: or consider using html button. But you wont be able to access your server side code then.(would have to use javascript instead)

Comment: In page load method write your code within if(!isPostback){ // code to set index to 0 } so that index will not be set to 0 every time you click the button.

What you need is an ajax call to a webmethod.

Comment: where are you changing the index of the image. Are  you using javascript to change the picture?

Comment: I dont have a postback property on my button. I dont know how to use the updatepannel. I tried with the html button and it didnt work. And I dont want to over complicate things with other stuff... just C# and just asp

Comment: Did you try my code? please see the answer and if you have any questions let me know.

Comment: I did just try your code Rebo but it seems way too complicated... I've barely even just begun web developing...

Comment: I am sorry to hear that, but you have to understand it and get used to those stuff in Web Development.
UpdatePanel : is useful for partial updates ( if you want to update a specific control on your webpage without refreshing it)

Comment: @user2235321 Please post your code so that your problem is more clear to me... And why you don't want to use ajax that's the best way to avoid postback....

Answer (score 4):

You need to use UpdatePanel for Partial Updates.

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" >
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="23px"  Width="24px" />

    <asp:Button ID="btnImageChange" runat="server" Text="Check" OnClick="btnImageChange_Click1"  />
     </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnImageChange" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Then in code behind .cs write this:

```
protected void btnImageChange_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     // you can add a loop here for the list of images...
            Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/loading.gif";

}
```

Comment: nope this didnt work... the image does not change because the load page method is still being called

Comment: I updated it... Please within the form tag ..add this line 

 <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

Comment: This is probably the most appropriate solution for the OP, the returning on the client-side is wrong because the server-side code (which the OP needs to execute) won't execute anyway.

Comment: @user2235321 Of course the Page_Load method is called, your button is posting back! Any page-instance server-side code _will_ execute the Page_Load handler, in order to prevent the code inside their executing, use the `if (!IsPostBack)` convention.

Comment: @ReboKoye If you add the `IsPostBack` condition in a Page_Load example in your answer, the OP will have everything they need, surely.

Comment: @GrantThomas: Yes right. It will be perfect with IsPostBack condition. but I think he needs to read more about  update panel and those concepts to understand it. coz as he said he is beginner.

Answer (score -1):

```
onClientClick="return false"
```

That should do it! Onclick will refer to an ASP.net function, onClientClick will render as OnClick on the control in HTML.

Comment: As you know it's render like onClick yet, it encapsules the client function as a guard... if you put return false means you'll never hit the server.

Answer (score -2):

on button click call this javascript functon

```
        <script type="text/Javascript">
     function ChangeIndex(){
      $.ajax({
                url: "Url of your page/Methodname",
                data: JSON.stringify({variableName,VariableValue}),
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    //set your image scr here 
                },
                error: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                    //alert('There was an error.');
                }

            }
      </script>
```

in your code behind write a webmethod

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string Methodname(string variableName)
    { 
      //Logic to get the index. 
      return "Index";
     }
```

Hope this helps.  Please post your code so that I can help you further.

Answer (score -2):

Try not to implement such old fashion buttons. Instead you can use `fly buttons` or `jQuery` triggered button which won't post back.